# Image as background in span not rendering

Tags: html

I have the following class

```
.stats {
    content: url('images/stats.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 23px;
    height: 20px;
    float: right;
}
```

and the following span

```
<span class="stats" ng-click="showTabDialog(player)"></span>
```

This renders fine in Chrome but I do not see the image in IE11 even though I can click in the place where the image should be and it works correctly

Why do I not see the image in IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you have `content: url('images/stats.gif')`? The `content` CSS property only works with pseudo-elements `::before` and `::after`. I would suggest to try setting it as a background-image:

```css
.stats {
  background-image: url('http://onlywm.ru/vbfs_aBlackRed/misc/stats.gif');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 23px;
  height: 20px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<span class="stats" ng-click="showTabDialog(player)"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

*content* CSS property only works with the ::before and ::after pseudo-elements:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content

Chrome doesn't respect the specifications in that regard.

You should use background-image.

Answer (score 1):

Add `display-block` to your css. The background-image CSS property only puts an image as the background. The width and height of an object is always defined either by static settings via CSS/inline styling, or by the actual size of the content displayed in it. In your case, since you haven't added any content between your tags, its x/y dimensions will be 0

```
.stats {
  width: 23px;
height: 20px;
    background-image: url('http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/5718897981_10faa45ac3_b-640x624.jpg') ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    float : right;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5a2fy2bL/)**

Answer (score 0):

three mandatory attributes in the css for rendering the image (other than the background-image):

```
height: 40px; //change size as needed
width: 40px; //change size as needed
display: block; //Tend to miss this one out
```

Without height and width, if your asset takes time to render, the element will not be alloted an region space. Without display: block, the image only exists in the background. (tried too many things before discovering this subtle mistake).

Other attributes are optional and needed based on your requirement of positioning the image.